# Finding the number of spanning trees for a graph

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

[image: G]

I just wanted to know if my answer is correct. I found 8 spanning trees by contracting the edge in the middle of the triangle.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the number of spanning trees is 8. We can verify it by considering the [Laplacian Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) of the graph
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2&-1&-1&0&0\\ -1&4&-1&-1&-1\\ -1&-1&3&-1&0\\ 0&-1&-1&2&0\\0&-1&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Hence, by [Kirchhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem), the number of spanning trees is equal to any cofactor of the Laplacian matrix. For example, by deleting the second row and the second column we obtain
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2&-1&0&0\\ -1&3&-1&0\\ 0&-1&2&0\\0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$
whose determinant is $2(6-1)+1(-2)=8$.